# If $n$ is a positive integer such that the sum of all positive integers $a$...

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck with the following problem that says:

> If $n$ is a positive integer such that the sum of all positive integers $a$ satisfying $1 \le a \le n$ and GCD $(a,n)=1$ is equal to $240n,$ then the number of summands ,namely,$\phi(n),$ is
>
> 1. $120$
> 2. $124$
> 3. $240$
> 4. $480$

MY TRY: Just for understanding, if  I take $n=5,$then $a_i$'s such that gcd $(a_i,5)=1$ and $\sum a_i=240\times 5$. But, $a_i$'s can only be $1,2,3,4$ ,since $n=5$. Now, I do not know which way to go.

Can someone explain? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,n) = \gcd(n-a,n)$.

Comment: still not sure how to utilize the hint..

Comment: You group the numbers you sum in pairs.

Comment: If the sum is $240n$, then $n$ must be larger than $240$. The sum is always at most $\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} a = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (except for $n = 1$). Nevertheless, looking at the corresponding sum for smaller $n$ can help. But you should take composite $n$ to get a real understanding of what's going on, for $n$ prime, $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ is not much of a restriction (it only pushes $n$ out of the sum, so the sum is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help drive some of the comments home.  You mentioned trying $n=5$.  That sum would be

$S=1+2+3+4$

$S=4+3+2+1$

Summing both equations

$2S=5+5+5+5$

Does this help?  Try for composite values of $n$ if necessary.